# Handling combinations of multiple conditions in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

We have wpf application in which we need to do some filtering based on multiple criteria's.We need to do combinations of these criteria's.We have many conditions in our filter. For that we are using if..else if and switch statements.But in future even one criteria increases,then we will need to modify our code and will need to revise code.I am unable to think any of the solution other than if..else if & switch statement.If you have any solution,please share it here.
 Following is code snippet.These are only few conditions but I guess this will be sufficient to know what my problem is.

```
if (SelectedDomicileRegion != null && !SelectedDomicileRegion.Equals("None") &&
   (SelectedDomicileCountry == null || SelectedDomicileCountry.Equals("None")) && 
   (SelectedMktCapOpeator == null || MktCapValue == null) && 
   salesRegionFilterCondn && salesCountryFilterCondn)
   {
      //some code here      
   }
else if ((SelectedDomicileRegion == null || SelectedDomicileRegion.Equals("None")) && 
  (SelectedMktCapOpeator == null || MktCapValue == null) && 
  (SelectedDomicileCountry != null && !SelectedDomicileCountry.Equals("None")) && 
  salesRegionFilterCondn && salesCountryFilterCondn)
  {
     //some code here
  }
else if (SelectedDomicileRegion != null && !SelectedDomicileRegion.Equals("None") && 
  SelectedDomicileCountry != null && SelectedDomicileCountry.Equals("None") && 
  (SelectedMktCapOpeator == null || MktCapValue == null) && 
  salesRegionFilterCondn && salesCountryFilterCondn)
  {
     //some code here
  }
else if (SelectedDomicileCountry != null && !SelectedDomicileCountry.Equals("None") && 
  SelectedMktCapOpeator != null && MktCapValue != null && 
  (SelectedDomicileRegion == null || SelectedDomicileRegion.Equals("None")) && 
  salesRegionFilterCondn && salesCountryFilterCondn)
  {
      //here again I need to do check conditions
      switch (SelectedMktCapOpeator)
      {
          case "is equal to": //some code here              
              break;
          case "is not equal to": //some code here
              break;
          case "is less than": //some code here
              break;
          case "is less than or equal to": //some code here
              break;
          case "is greater than": //some code here
              break;
          case "is greater than or equal to": //some code here
              break;
      }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post your current code, in order we have a common base of talking? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you post code we might be able to help

Comment: @Christos I have post code please have look at it.Thank you

Comment: @Tsukasa I have edited my question and have added code.please have look at it.Thank you

Comment: @DTsawant looks normal to me. I suppose we're seeing the contents of your filter delegate for the collectionviewsource?

Comment: @AndreasMüller Each filter is collection of items.So we need to combine each item with other and so on.

Comment: @DTsawant I see. I'll try to set up an answer then.

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario sounds similar to this:

Usually if you want to mix results from different objects i would be going this way:

```
public class FilterSample : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<Car> Cars { get; private set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Motorcycle> Motorcycles { get; private set; }
    public ObservableCollection<IVehicle> AllVehicles { get; private set; }

    public FilterSample()
    {
        Cars = new ObservableCollection<Car>();
        Motorcycles = new ObservableCollection<Motorcycle>();
        AllVehicles = new ObservableCollection<IVehicle>();

        CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(AllVehicles).Filter = AllVehicleFilter;
    }

    private bool AllVehicleFilter(object o)
    {
        IVehicle vehicle = o as IVehicle;

        vehicle = o as IVehicle;
        if (vehicle == null)
            return false;

        Car car = o as Car;
        Motorcycle motorcycle = o as Motorcycle;

        if (car != null)
        {
            switch (CurrentRegion)
            {
                 // custom handling 
            }
        }

        // etc
    }

    public string CurrentRegion { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class Car : IVehicle
{
    public int Tires { get { return 4; } }
}

public class Motorcycle : IVehicle
{
    public int Tires { get { return 2; } }
}

public interface IVehicle
{
    int Tires { get; }
}
```

Comment: will this reduce conditions in switch and if..else if statements?

Comment: Unless you extract your validation into methods which are used by multiple filters (which you mentioned) you won't reduce conditions no. This is pretty much what the filter usually looks like i'm afraid